# Horizontal rule: how to?

Tags: java, android, xml

i would like to know how to insert an horizontal rule between the first textview and the second. The code is this. I searched on google and found various codes but they do not work for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/desc" 
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Between the two `TextView`s, add a simple `View`, give it the `background` you want (a color or an image) and make it as high as you need the rule to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Testing"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <View android:id="@+id/divider"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="2dp"
          android:background="@android:color/white"

          android:layout_below="@id/text"
            />

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Testing"

            android:layout_below="@id/divider"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other guy said just add a view between them..so now your code should like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/desc" 
    />

    <View 
    android:background="#266E10"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```